# SFCC change password policies for customer

Tags: demandware

I'm on SFCC project , I'm wondering where to change the password policies for customers.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Check in Business Manager

> Administration >  Sites >  Customer Lists > site_id.

In the General tab you have all kinds of restrictions for the password.

Comment: Note: 'site_id' is actually the ID of the customer list in this context. In the SFRA reference data the Customer List IDs are the same as the Site IDs but that may not always be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps,

1. Login in to Business Manager.
2. Navigate to Administration >  Sites >  Customer Lists
3. Click on the 'Edit' link on the right side of your customer list.
4. Under the "Customer Login Settings" section you can modify the password rules.